# Update cells in spreadsheet using VBS - changing input format when saving file

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have the following input for a csv file:

```
s,asdaas, 123123.00,asdasd
 123123.00,bubu1,wqeqw,asd
asdasd,asdasd
```

and I'm using the following vbs:

```
On Error Resume Next
    sheet_number = CInt(Wscript.Arguments.Item(1))
    row_index = CInt(Wscript.Arguments.Item(2))
    col_index = CInt(Wscript.Arguments.Item(3))

    value_insert = Wscript.Arguments.Item(4)
    if value_insert <> "" then
        c = Replace(value_insert, "#", Chr(10))
    end if

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))

    Dim oExcel
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Dim oBook
    Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)

    if sheet_number = 0 Then
        sheet_number = 1
    end if
    oBook.Sheets(sheet_number).Select
    oExcel.Cells(row_index,col_index).NumberFormat = "@"
    oExcel.Cells(row_index,col_index).Select
    oExcel.Cells(row_index,col_index).Value2 = value_insert
    oBook.Save
    oBook.Close
    oExcel.Quit
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    oBook.Close False
    oExcel.Quit
    Err.Clear             ' Clear the Error
End If
```

If for example i try to update value from row 2, column 2 from "bubu1" to "oi", other cells will be affected when saving the file. For example the " 123123.00" will become "123123", note that the .00 and the space are gone.

Is there a way to prevent this?
After being modified the csv file is being sent to another process that cannot handle the file with these "auto" changes.

Current output:

```
s,asdaas,123123,asdasd
123123,oi,wqeqw,asd
asdasd,asdasd
```

Desired output:

```
s,asdaas, 123123.00,asdasd
 123123.00,oi,wqeqw,asd
asdasd,asdasd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using ExcelApplication to deal with CSV's.

Instead I used: http://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads_ActiveX.asp

Did exactly what i needed.